# Calculus Electricity problem

Tags: calculus

[image]

I think I have an idea about how to solve this I just wanted to make sure.

For number 1, my idea is just to plug in 155 for A then take the integral and then the square root of that to get the RMS? but now that i think about it, i dont know what T is. is T something that i should be able to figure out?

for number 2 , my idea is to work backwards and solve for A. Is that the right approach?

Comment: $T$ is the period of $V(t)$, i.e., that number such that $V(t+T) = V(t)$. So $T=1/60$.

Comment: @NickThompson:  I think that is an answer.  If you post it, I will vote for it.  You might add a comment that this factor is common to all sine waves if you want.

Comment: why is it 1/60?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are given: $V(t) = A \sin wt = 155 \sin 120 \pi t$

$\displaystyle w = 2 \pi f = \frac{2 \pi}{T} = 120 \pi \rightarrow T = \frac{1}{60}$

$$\displaystyle V_{rms} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{T} \int^T_{0} V(t)^2} = \sqrt{60 \int^{\frac{1}{60}}_{0} (A \sin 120 \pi t)^2} =  0.0821873 A$$

For the given value, we have:

$\displaystyle V_{rms} = 0.0821873 A = 12.7390315$ Volts.

If a voltmeter reads $220$ Volts, we have an amplitude of:

$$\displaystyle 0.0821873 A = 220 \rightarrow A = \frac{220}{0.0821873} = 2676.8125975$$

Comment: +1 Great guidance and follow-through! Modeling at its best ;-)

Comment: My electronics skills are severely degraded and they were excellent at one point! Thanks

Comment: what is w? is V(t) = A sinwt a known function?

Comment: $w = \omega$ - I was just lazy. I used a general solution for 'any' amplitude. Also, if $\omega = 2 \pi f$, we would get $V_{rms} = .707 A$. You gave $V(t)$, a known function. Clear?